# kendo ui select a specifix index/text during first load

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox, kendo-dropdown

The problem i am running into is that during the first load of the page i want to read the value from cookies if found, i want to change the theme that was stored in the cookie.
not only want to change the them but i also want to select that item in the combo box so that it is in sync with the them that was applied.

How can i select a specific item during initial page load, when i am constructing the combobox ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   var initialized = false;
        // theme chooser drop-down
        var cmb=$(".themeChooser").kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: [
                    { text: "Default" },
                    { text: "BlueOpal" },
                    { text: "Bootstrap" },
                    { text: "Silver" },
                    { text: "Uniform" },
                    { text: "Metro" },
                    { text: "Black" },
                    { text: "MetroBlack" },
                    { text: "HighContrast" },
                    { text: "Moonlight" }
            ],
            dataTextField: "text",
            dataValueField: "value",
            change: function (e) {

                $.cookie('selectedTheme', theme);
                changeTheme(theme);

            }
        });

        theme = ($.cookie('selectedTheme') || "default").toLowerCase();
        //Not sure how to trigger the select of combobox
        cmb.value(theme);  // no effect                       
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get a reference to the dropdown list

```
var dropdownlist = $("#Instrument").data("kendoDropDownList");
```

If you know the index you can use:

```
// selects by index
dropdownlist.select(1);
```

If not, use:

```
// selects item if its text is equal to "test" using predicate function
dropdownlist.select(function(dataItem) {
    return dataItem.symbol === "test";
});
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/mRmNJ/

Comment: If you have set a name for the drop down list's "DataTextField", use that name instead of "symbol" in the above answer.

Answer (score 1):

See [Kendo Documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist#methods-select)

I believe in your case it would be some call like so:

```
//trigger the select of combobox 
cmb.select(function(dataItem) {
    return dataItem.text === theme;
});
```

Or just set the [value](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist#configuration-value) property in the object initializer

```
value = ($.cookie('selectedTheme') || "default").toLowerCase(),
```